# Reshaping a Pandas data frame with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

Using the using the `Plotly go.Table()` function and `Pandas`, I'm attempting to create a table to summarize some data.  My data is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Brokertec', 'DWAS', 'Ford', 'Buick'],
                          'Metric':['Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator'],
                          'Dimension':['Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Long', 'Short', 'Short', 'Long', 'Long'],
                          'User': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'New USA', 'USA', 'Los USA'],
                          'Value':[50, 3, 3, 2, 5, 7, 10, 5]
                   })
```

My desired output is as follows (summing the `Dimension` by `Manufacturer`):

```
Manufacturer        Short        Long
Chrysler            6            2
Buick               5            5
Mercedes            7            0
Ford                0            10
```

I need to shape the Pandas data frame a bit (and this is where I'm running into trouble).  My code was as follows:

```
table_columns = ['Manufacturer', 'Longs', 'Shorts']

manufacturers = ['Chrysler', 'Buick', 'Mercedes', 'Ford']

df_new = (df[df['Manufacturer'].isin(manufacturers)]
                        .set_index(['Manufacturer', 'Dimension'])
                        ['Value'].unstack()
                        .reset_index()[table_columns]
                        )
```

Then, create the table using the `Plotly go.Table()` function:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

direction_table = go.Figure(go.Table(
                                header=dict(
                                    values=table_columns,
                                    font=dict(size=12),
                                    line_color='darkslategray',
                                    fill_color='lightskyblue',
                                    align='center'
                                    ),
                                cells=dict(
                                    values=df_new.T,   # using Transpose here
                                    line_color='darkslategray',
                                    fill_color='lightcyan',
                                    align = 'center')
                                )
                )

direction_table
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

What is the best way to work around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pivot_table` with aggfunc='sum' instead of `set_index.unstack`

```
table_columns = ['Manufacturer', 'Long', 'Short']

manufacturers = ['Chrysler', 'Buick', 'Mercedes', 'Ford']

df_new = (test_df[test_df['Manufacturer'].isin(manufacturers)]
               .pivot_table(index='Manufacturer', columns='Dimension', 
                            values='Value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
               .reset_index()
               .rename_axis(columns=None)[table_columns]
        )
print (df_new)
  Manufacturer  Long  Short
0        Buick     5      0
1     Chrysler     2      6
2         Ford    10      0
```

Note it is not the same output but I don't think your input can give the expected output

Or the same result with `groupby.sum` and `unstack`

```
(test_df[test_df['Manufacturer'].isin(manufacturers)]
        .groupby(['Manufacturer', 'Dimension'])
        ['Value'].sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)[table_columns]
)
```